# Define and initialize stl constant in one line

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

I have a class:

```
Temp.h:
[...]
class Temp{
public:
    Temp(vector<vector<double> > vect);
    const static Temp VAR1;
    const static Temp VAR2;
    ...

};
```

I want to initialize VAR1 and VAR2 using array of doubles: {{0,1,0,1},{1,0,1,0}}. But I cannot do this like this:

```
const Temp::VAR1(...);
```

, because there is no 'one-line' operator to construct vector of vectors from an array of arrays. I thought about building structure, like:

```
B{
    vector<vector<double> > vect;

    B& add (double[] a, int number) {... 
    push elements from array to vector and add this vector to vect ...
    return *this;
    }

    Temp build() {return Temp(vect);}
}
```

But when I call:

```
 B().add({0,1,0,1},4).add({1,0,1,0},4).build();
```

Compiler doesn't recognize {0,1,0,1} as an array, but as a double* and I cannot change it.

Is there any option to create some method or something similar to initialize const static member in more lines than one?

I hope I wrote simple enough, if not, I'll edit it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11, use the uniform initialisation syntax:

```
const Temp::VAR1{{0,1,0,1},{1,0,1,0}};
```

If you have to remain compatible with C++03, I'd recommend using [`boost::assign`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
const Temp::VAR1 = list_of(list_of(0)(1)(0)(1))(list_of(1)(0)(1)(0));
```

Comment: C++11 answer is simply amazing. Where can I read sth about C++11 standard? ISO/IEC webpage is too expensive.

Comment: Yes, it is! The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) covers lots of ground and has a link to a freely downloadable draft version of the standard. Herb Sutter's article [Elements of Modern C++ Style](http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/) is very readable and a great overview with many interesting links to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Write a static function that initializes it:

```
Temp InitTempVar1()
{
    vector<vector<double> > init;
    // initialize init...
    return Temp(init);
}

Temp InitTempVar2()
{
    vector<vector<double> > init;
    // initialize init...
    return Temp(init);
}

const Temp Temp::VAR1 = InitTempVar1();
const Temp Temp::VAR2 = InitTempVar2();
```